# Text animation in Javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, animation

I want to make a looping animation by adding other texts character by character, removing them in the same way and changing the text before starting the loop. But, as you can see [**in this GIF**](https://i.imgur.com/Bqpi4LN.gif), everything goes wrong.

This is how my code looks right now:

HTML
`<h1 id="title">Desenvolvedor </h1>`

JS

```
const title = document.getElementById("title");
const stacks = ["Front-End", "Back-End", "Full Stack"];
const speed = 200;
let stackIndex = 0;
let i = 0;

function addChar() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    title.innerHTML += stacks[stackIndex].charAt(i);
    i++;
    typeWriter(stackIndex);
  }, speed);
}

function deleteChar() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    title.innerHTML = title.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
    
    if (title.innerText.length > 13) {
      deleteChar();
    } else {
      if (stackIndex > 1) {
        i = 0;
        stackIndex = 0;
        typeWriter(stackIndex);
      }

      i = 0;
      typeWriter(stackIndex++);
    }

  }, speed);
}

function typeWriter(stackIndex) {
  if (i < stacks[stackIndex].length) {
    addChar();
  } else {
    deleteChar();
  }
}
```

Adding the texts and changing their values worked as expected, but when it comes to resetting the values from **stackIndex** and **i** and starting the animation again, it starts to present bugs, even though in theory it is repeating the entire code from scratch.
How do I fix this error? Is there any more practical way to do this animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code. Hope it works for you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Text Animation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="title">Desenvolvedor </h1>

    <script>
        const title = document.getElementById("title");
        const stacks = ["Front-End", "Back-End", "Full Stack"];
        const speed = 200;

        async function animateText() {
            for (let stackIndex = 0; stackIndex < stacks.length; stackIndex++) {
                await typeWriter(stackIndex);
                await sleep(1000); // Add a delay between texts
                await deleteText();
            }
            animateText(); // Loop the animation
        }

        async function typeWriter(stackIndex) {
            for (let i = 0; i < stacks[stackIndex].length; i++) {
                await sleep(speed);
                title.innerHTML += stacks[stackIndex].charAt(i);
            }
        }

        async function deleteText() {
            while (title.innerText.length > 13) {
                await sleep(speed);
                title.innerHTML = title.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
            }
        }

        function sleep(ms) {
            return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
        }

        animateText(); // Start the animation
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```